# How sort objects parsed from XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, parsing, ios

so I want to parse an xml and display (in a UITableView) the "subjects" in ascending order depending on "lessons"

XML:

```
<parfumeo_kkn>
<tt_timetable>
    <id>1015</id>
    <day>1</day>
    <class_id>98</class_id>
    <lesson>9</lesson>
    <teacher>bt</teacher>
    <room>V1.2</room>
    <subject>M</subject>
    <pr_id>54</pr_id>
</tt_timetable>
<tt_timetable>
    <id>1014</id>
    <day>1</day>
    <class_id>98</class_id>
    <lesson>8</lesson>
    <teacher>bt</teacher>
    <room>V1.2</room>
    <subject>bg</subject>
    <pr_id>54</pr_id>
</tt_timetable>
```

ect.

(In this little example there would be "bg" before "M".) I allready set up my parser but it's not working in the order I want it to.
thx for help

Comment: When the call back calls for each start element you check for particular element type, for your case will be lesson and corresponding subjects. Put those pair in dictionary which you can add in some container. And later you can use it according to your wish.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. BUT: all i get is this:

Comment: {
    lesson = "9\n        8\n        11\n        11\n        10\n        10\n        5\n        4\n        3\n        2\n        1\n        ";
    subject = "bg\n        bg\n        CAE\n        CAE\n        CAE\n        CAE\n        Gg\n        G\n        G\n        M\n        M\n        ";

Comment: and furthermore now only 1 cell is filled with the whole array.. ^^ I should give it up seriously ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate the logic of the parser and how you display the results in the table views. The parser just does its task of parsing the xml, the controller for the table view will do a little bit extra task by ordering the results from the parser by using NSSortDescriptor, an example follows:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lesson" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Yes, previously I am assuming you're using Core Data, in case you just have a normal array, then you can just simply call:

```
    NSArray *myArray = [xmlResultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Now you can use myArray to populate to your table view controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: He is assuming you are using core data.

Comment: thanks alot.. but still not working.. I put your lines in 
-(void)parserDidEnddocument: 
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lesson" ascending:YES]autorelease];
 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
 [stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

maybe I got it wrong but my output remains the same..

Comment: hi dav3, see my edited answer. You have to use the result from the call to sortedArrayUsingDescriptors to populate to the table view. I thought you know that, sorry.

Comment: thanks sfa... I just redifined my array instead of using a new one...

    resultArray = [resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

don't know if that's clever but it kind of worked..

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting the answer as it will let other people know where the answer to your question is!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can parse you XML file, put objects in a array then sort this array ?

```
NSArray *myArray = [parser parseTheFile:file];
[self sortTheArray:myArray];
```

Comment: the response just above is better than mine.

Comment: =) but I wanted to thank you too... unfortunately I'm too nooby to use it correctly.. :-/

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array you just do this.

```
NSArray *sortedPairs = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

If you have a dictionary and want to get a sorted array by keys you'd

```
NSArray *arr = [dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

once you have your array you can enumerate as you wish.